# Ruby Dashboard - Dashing - needs rails to run?

Tags: ruby, dashing

Trying to set up the sample project following the instructions found on the project page for [Dashing](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/). 
When starting up using the command: **$ dashing start**, nothing happens, no errors, no output, nothing.

I have not install rails and its not mentioned as a requirement in the instructions, but is it needed for Dashing to run?

Any ideas how to trace this, or what might be wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the `dashing` gem is working, by following the steps outlined on [this page](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/):

1. gem install dashing
2. dashing new sweet_dashboard_project
3. bundle
4. dashing start

I tried the above steps before posting this as an answer, and everything seems to work nicely.
However, I needed to comment everything inside `jobs/twitter.rb` file (you can, alternatively, add your twitter API credentials to that file)

Comment: Something must have gone wrong before during the bundle step. When I re-run it, this error occurred: _An error occurred while installing memoizable (0.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue._ Installing memoizable went ok, but now **dashing start** throws an error: _C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.0/ruby_http_parser_ (LoadError) ..._